# Запятая перед "да" [1]

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

> Какой праздник(,) да без подарков!

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед словом "да"?

Comment: Это нормальный риторический вопрос: Да какой праздник без подарков. Без слова «какой» вопрос не состоится.

Answer (score 11):

"Какой праздник да без подарков?!"

Дополнительных знаков препинания не требуется. "Да" в этом предложении не союз, а усилительная частица, употреблённая для придания большей выразительности последующим словам.

Примеры из книг:

Что за праздник да без танца, надо к танцам возвращаться!

Такой праздник да без Ивана Парфеновича!

Разве может быть у нас настоящий праздник да без греха?

Comment: ОФФТОП (чат не могу создать) 

@slava1947 Пожалуйста, будете на "Грамоте", напишите ***ne znatok***, что я очень хочу с ней поговорить по вопросам, которые она задала Е. О.
Бегемот behemothus@mail.ru

Comment: @behemothus Сейчас попробую. А она знает, как с Вами связаться?

Comment: Ой, извините! Не заметил, что адрес Вы указали...

Comment: Благодарю премного.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая перед *да* **не нужна**, поскольку союз *да* выступает здесь в роли (в значении) соединительного союза *и*. Какой праздник *и* без подарков!

Comment: Скорее, вместо — если. Нужна запятая.

Comment: Не нужна запятая. См. ответ slava1947.

Comment: За большевиков будете?

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1.** **Какой** праздник (да) без подарков?!  Это **риторический** вопрос (скрытое утверждение).

**Вариант 2.** **Такой** праздник (да) без подарков! (Конечно, нет, подарки обязательно будут). Это утверждение, но такую конструкцию можно назвать скрытым отрицанием  сказанного.

Таким образом, по смыслу эти варианта сходны между собой, в них используется усилительная частиц ДА, которую можно изъять из предложения.  Но есть еще **присоединительный союз ДА** (указывает на развитие, дополнение, пояснение).

**Тексты с частицей ДА встречаются чаще, но и присоединительный союз ДА тоже не исключение**, например: А какой же праздник, да без подарков? В гости, да без подарков! И как же на **такой** праздник, да без песен и плясок? Да какая же деревня, да без русской бани! А какая баня, да без веничка!   Как же бал, да без меня? Ну и что за праздник, да без закуски! **Но встречается запись тех же  самых выражений  и без запятой.**

Подводя итог, можно сказать следующее:  **присоединительный союз ДА**  с запятой желательно использовать только в том случае, если предложение распространенное (то есть не является простым восклицанием) и явно делится паузой на две части: **Не может быть праздника, да без сюрприза! А как же на русском празднике, да без угощения! Сравнить: Русский праздник да без угощения!

Comment: Вряд ли дело в интонации; важнее общий смысл: от него зависит выполняемая словом "да" функция (присоединительный или противительный союз, либо частица). Праздник, да без подарков (сетование об отсутствии подарков на празднике; "да" - противительный союз, синоним "но", ср. "Федот, да не тот"). Какой праздник да без подарков?! (Конечно же, они были; "да"- частица; пауза может быть сделана здесь без изменения смысла; может быть опущена и частица) Это был праздник, да с подарками! ("да" - присоед. союз)

Comment: Интонация связана со смыслом, это форма предложения, помогающая понять смысл.  Смысл заданного предложения:  Какой праздник, ЕСЛИ НЕТ подарков? Пауза и запятая соответствуют этому содержанию.  Такой праздник да без подарков - это УТВЕРЖДЕНИЕ того, что подарки БЫЛИ.

Answer (score 2):

По правилам (вроде бы) выходит, что запятая не нужна, "да" - усилительная частица. Но "пустая" фраза совершенно не смотрится. Я бы поставил тире как знак противопоставления, в чем-то неожиданного перехода, излома фраза.

***Какой праздник - да без подарков!***

Остальное - см. slava1947